# Issue with JavaScript auto-check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to check if a new build of my software has been posted using jQuery.get(); by calling a PHP script then getting what it returns and going off of that. Here is my code:

JavaScript Code:

```
var old_count = 0;
$.get("api/build/update-check.php", function(data) {
    old_count = data;
});

window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get("api/build/update-check.php", function(data) {
        var count = old_count;
        if(old_count < count)
            console.warn("There is a new build available!");
        console.log("Old Count: " + old_count);
        console.log("New Count: " + count);
        old_count = count;
    });
    console.info("Checked for new builds successfully!");
}, 5000);
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$fi = new FilesystemIterator("../../download/builds/", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$count = iterator_count($fi) - 1; //Subtract the .htaccess file

echo $count;
```

It will run everything perfectly once and it will re-run the method like its supposed to fine, however, when it re-runs the script, it doesn't change the variable.  I know for a fact that the PHP script works fine as I have tested it.  I think the issue is that it gets the check script one time then keeps that for the use during the interval. Is there a way to make it call the PHP script every time or what do I need to change to make it work the way I intend?

Comment: In your second ajax request you are not using data, you are however setting count to old_count, and immediately trying to test if they are different which they wont be because you just set them to be equal to each other

Comment: Is it caching the results of the PHP file? If so, you could prevent caching with an HTML header, or add a random number to the request.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! That was the problem. I looked right over that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is the problem

```
var count = old_count;
if(old_count < count)
```

They are 100% equal, how these values can be different?

I think you mean

```
var count = data;
```

in this place ;)

```
var old_count = 0;
$.get("api/build/update-check.php", function(data) {
    old_count = data;
});

window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get("api/build/update-check.php", function(data) {
        // count = data instead of old_count. You assign old_count = count later
        var count = data;
        if(old_count < count)
            console.warn("There is a new build available!");
        console.log("Old Count: " + old_count);
        console.log("New Count: " + count);
        old_count = count;
    });
    console.info("Checked for new builds successfully!");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent caching by requesting the PHP page with a random query string like this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get("api/build/update-check.php?"+Math.random(), function(data) {
        // ...
    });
    console.info("Checked for new builds successfully!");
}, 5000);
```